# Switch Active View Controller Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have 2 views as part of my Navigation Controller.

I created a class for my Navigation Controller with a public method that certain actions on the first view will trigger to load the Detail View Controller. I am importing the Detail View Controller, but nothing in my code is working. I know the method is being called correctly because I'm logging it.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NearbyController : UINavigationController

- (void) nextpage;

@end

#import "NearbyController.h"
#import "DetailView.h"

@implementation NearbyController


-(void) nextpage {
    NSLog(@"working");

    DetailView *nextView = [[DetailView alloc] init];
    [self pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize a view controller programmatically you should use this [init](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a).

Answer (score 0):

If you have set a storyboard ID you can do this

```
DetailView *nextView = (DetailView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewControllerID"];
[self pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

If you want to load from a XIB you can call

```
DetailView *nextView = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyDetailViewControllerID" bundle:nil];
[self pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm getting this error:Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <NearbyController: 0xb98ce90>.

Comment: It means the view controller u r trying to push has not been allocated properly. Pls check the allocation of the view controller and see if its allocated cleanly

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards what you wanna do is setup the storyboard id in the identity inspector on your DetailViewViewController

Then you would wanna instantiate your view controller like so:

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 DetailView *nextView =[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewViewController"];
 /* your identifier is your storyboard id*/
 sb = nextView.storyboard;
```

Then you should be able to push your view controller.
Im still new to this but i hope this helps!